# Problem with selenium scraper, indexError

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, index-error

this is my code, 
it is used to take various data from an online warehouse and report it in a csv

```
class Selenium:

#find_element_by_name('')
#find_element_by_xpath('')
#find_elements_by_class_name('')
#find_element_by_id('')
# giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tdLarghezzaArt > .clFascia .tdwithAut > .testoGiac')
# giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiacVal')
# giacenza2 = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiacVal')

def __init__(self, webdriver, x, y):
    with open('File-Results.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write("Codice ;Prezzo; Giacenza \n")

        def testo_prezzo():
            prezzo = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoPrezzo')
            return prezzo

        def giacenza():
            giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiac')
            return giacenza

        def giacenza_2():
            giacenza2 = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.testoGiacVal')
            return giacenza2
        # self.giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiacVal')

        def codice_prodotto():
            codice = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testo_codiceArt')
            return codice

        def for_def():
            # cnt = 0
            test = len(giacenza())
            with open('File-Results.csv', 'a') as f:
                for i in range(test):
                    if giacenza()[i].text == "Disponibile":
                        giac = giacenza()[i].text
                        print(1, codice_prodotto()[i].text + " " + giac)
                    else:
                        giac = giacenza_2()[i].text
                        print(2,codice_prodotto()[i].text + " " + giac)

                    f.write(
                        codice_prodotto()[i].text + ";" + testo_prezzo()[i].text + ";" + giac + "\n")

    self.username = webdriver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(x)
    self.password = webdriver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(y)
    time.sleep(3)
    self.login = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "buttonLogin", " " ))]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.cookie = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("buttonCookie").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    self.SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 20

    self.last_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:

        webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(self.SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        self.new_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if self.new_height == self.last_height:
            break
        self.last_height = self.new_height

        for_def()

    time.sleep(5)
    webdriver.close()

    self.end_msg = messagebox.showinfo(title="\t", message="Grazie per aver utilizzato ReadyDrop")
```

at the end of the cycle the code should be 'disponibile' for products without 'giacenza' and inventory for those with 'giacenza'

instead of continuing the program crashes returning this error:

> giac = giacenza_2()[i].text IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`giacenza()` and `giacenza_2()` seem to have contain a different number of elements at times that lead to error. Adding check for giacenza_2 can help avoiding error:

```
class Selenium:

#find_element_by_name('')
#find_element_by_xpath('')
#find_elements_by_class_name('')
#find_element_by_id('')
# giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tdLarghezzaArt > .clFascia .tdwithAut > .testoGiac')
# giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiacVal')
# giacenza2 = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiacVal')

 def __init__(self):
    with open('./File-Results.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write("Codice ;Prezzo; Giacenza \n")

        def testo_prezzo():
            prezzo = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoPrezzo')
            return prezzo

        def giacenza():
            giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiac')
            return giacenza

        def giacenza_2():
            giacenza2 = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.testoGiacVal')
            return giacenza2
        # self.giacenza = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testoGiacVal')

        def codice_prodotto():
            codice = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('testo_codiceArt')
            return codice

        def for_def():
            # cnt = 0
            test = len(giacenza())
            with open('File-Results.csv', 'a') as f:
                for i in range(test):
                    if len(giacenza())<=i and giacenza()[i].text == "Disponibile":
                        giac = giacenza()[i].text
                        print(1, codice_prodotto()[i].text + " " + giac)
                    else:
                            if giacenza_2()<=i:
                                    giac = giacenza_2()[i].text
                                    print(2,codice_prodotto()[i].text + " " + giac)
                                    f.write(codice_prodotto()[i].text + ";" + testo_prezzo()[i].text + ";" + giac + "\n")

    self.username = webdriver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(x)
    self.password = webdriver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(y)
    time.sleep(3)
    self.login = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "buttonLogin", " " ))]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.cookie = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("buttonCookie").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    self.SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 20

    self.last_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:

        webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(self.SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        self.new_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if self.new_height == self.last_height:
            break
        self.last_height = self.new_height

        for_def()

    time.sleep(5)
    webdriver.close()

    self.end_msg = messagebox.showinfo(title="\t", message="Grazie per aver utilizzato ReadyDrop")
ob = Selenium()
ob.for_def()
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it gives me this error: if len(giacenza_2() <= i):
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: minor correction len(giacenza_2()<=i) is missing brackets. Please update it and use "len(giacenza_2())<=i: "

Comment: thanks again, the program still returns an error:     codice_prodotto()[i].text + ";" + testo_prezzo()[i].text + ";" + giac + "\n")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'giac' referenced before assignment

Comment: my bad, left out " f.write(
                        codice_prodotto()[i].text + ";" + testo_prezzo()[i].text + ";" + giac + "\n")" from if else. Please include this lint in if section of the above code

Comment: always return the same error, could you please write me the complete code?

Comment: Can you paste complete error mesage that you are getting?

Comment: File "C:/Users/Utente-XB/Desktop/App/App.py", line 199, in __init__
    for_def()
  File "C:/Users/Utente-XB/Desktop/App/App.py", line 173, in for_def
    f.write(codice_prodotto()[i].text + ";" + testo_prezzo()[i].text + ";" + giac + "\n")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'giac' referenced before assignment

Comment: my mistake, it started but stopped by returning this error:
    giac = giacenza_2()[i].text
IndexError: list index out of rang

Comment: Updated code in answer. Please check again it should be fine now

Comment: if giacenza_2()<=i:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Please try if giacenza_2()<=i: to if len(giacenza_2())<=i:

Comment: giac = giacenza_2()[i].text
IndexError: list index out of range